# not compiling... NarrowBand Twillio T-Mobile

Tags: arduino, seeeduino

regarding the...
NarrowBand Twillio T-Mobile
Wio LTE Cat-NB-IoT(SARA-N41)
V1.0 7/17/2018

I am using OSx 10.15.4 Beta (19E234g)
I installed Apple Command Line Tools...  as per
[No matching function for call in Arduino Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905366/no-matching-function-for-call-in-arduino-library)
looking for some suggestions on what to do next.

```
Arduino: 1.8.7 (Mac OS X), Board: "Seeeduino Stalker V3"

/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/vincentyoumans/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=Seeeduino:Seeeduino_Stalker:stalker -ide-version=10807 -build-path /var/folders/z2/4tjgj0hx69n2wvxs_43cc0km0000gn/T/arduino_build_122899 -warnings=all -build-cache /var/folders/z2/4tjgj0hx69n2wvxs_43cc0km0000gn/T/arduino_cache_376983 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages/Seeeduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-4.8.1-arduino5.path=/Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages/Seeeduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages/Seeeduino/tools/avrdude/6.0.1-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.0.1-arduino5.path=/Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages/Seeeduino/tools/avrdude/6.0.1-arduino5 -verbose /var/folders/z2/4tjgj0hx69n2wvxs_43cc0km0000gn/T/untitled1739366022.tmp/sketch_feb23a/sketch_feb23a.ino
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/vincentyoumans/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=Seeeduino:Seeeduino_Stalker:stalker -ide-version=10807 -build-path /var/folders/z2/4tjgj0hx69n2wvxs_43cc0km0000gn/T/arduino_build_122899 -warnings=all -build-cache /var/folders/z2/4tjgj0hx69n2wvxs_43cc0km0000gn/T/arduino_cache_376983 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages/Seeeduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-4.8.1-arduino5.path=/Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages/Seeeduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages/Seeeduino/tools/avrdude/6.0.1-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.0.1-arduino5.path=/Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages/Seeeduino/tools/avrdude/6.0.1-arduino5 -verbose /var/folders/z2/4tjgj0hx69n2wvxs_43cc0km0000gn/T/untitled1739366022.tmp/sketch_feb23a/sketch_feb23a.ino
Using board 'stalker' from platform in folder: /Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages/Seeeduino/hardware/Seeeduino_Stalker/1.0.2
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: /Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages/Seeeduino/hardware/Seeeduino_Stalker/1.0.2
Detecting libraries used...
/Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages/Seeeduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=8000000L -DARDUINO=10807 -DARDUINO_AVR_stalker -DARDUINO_ARCH_SEEEDUINO_STALKER -I/Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages/Seeeduino/hardware/Seeeduino_Stalker/1.0.2/cores/arduino -I/Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages/Seeeduino/hardware/Seeeduino_Stalker/1.0.2/variants/eightanaloginputs /var/folders/z2/4tjgj0hx69n2wvxs_43cc0km0000gn/T/arduino_build_122899/sketch/sketch_feb23a.ino.cpp -o /dev/null
fork/exec /Users/vincentyoumans/Library/Arduino15/packages/Seeeduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++: bad CPU type in executable
Error compiling for board Seeeduino Stalker V3.
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used "Seeeduino Stalker V3" myself but I bet you need to locate the compiler script file in the hardware folder, right click on it and choose open, then confirm that you want to open the file. macOS does this with many things downloaded from untrusted suppliers. You only have to do it once.